# Https server starting forever

Tags: python, python-3.x, https

So I got this https server from the internet and I created the certificate and the key file with this command:

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -days 365
```

And this is my code (Python 3):

```
import ssl
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer


class testHTTPServer_RequestHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    # GET
    def do_GET(self):
        # Send response status code
        self.send_response(200)

        # Send headers
        self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/html')
        self.end_headers()

        # Send message back to client
        message = "Hello world!"
        # Write content as utf-8 data
        self.wfile.write(bytes(message, "utf8"))
        return


def run():
    print('starting server...')
    server_address = ('127.0.0.1', 1234)
    httpd = HTTPServer(server_address, testHTTPServer_RequestHandler)
    httpd.socket = ssl.wrap_socket(httpd.socket, certfile='cert.pem',keyfile='key.pem',  server_side=True)
    print('running server...')
    httpd.serve_forever()


run()
```

But every time I run this code it stops at 'starting server...'
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Has your keyfile a password?

Comment: Yes, when creating the certificates I added one. Still, don't know what the problem is.

Comment: I cannot test here now, but did the server ask you for the passphrase? Do it the other way round: create a certificate/key with ``-nodes`` parameter and test if it works.

Comment: Thank you @allo, this worked for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your key was generated with a passphrase and the server cannot read it without the correct passphrase. You need either to use the ssl module in a way, that you unlock the key with the passphrase, or use a key without passphrase, i.e. generated with the `-nodes` parameter.